# Using MSDeploy for deploy of console application to a DMZ server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy a console application to a folder on a DMZ server using autodeploy with MSBuild and Team Foundation Server.

I am already deploying multiple sites to that same server and it works great. I have tried multiple ways but the files are not deployed.

First, I tried to deploy the console app in the same way as i do for my web site, ie:

```
<MSBuild
    Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\MySolution.sln"
    Properties="AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;AuthType=Basic;
    Configuration=DEBUG;CreatePackageOnPublish=True;                                
    DeployIisAppPath=Default Website/dummy.dev.myapp;
    DeployOnBuild=True;DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish;
    MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc;
    MsDeployServiceUrl=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd;
    UserName=userid;Password=password;UseMsdeployExe=True"
/>
```

Without success.

*EDIT: No error message is returned. It all seems to go well.*

Then, I also tried to deploy the console app as follows:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\MSDeploy.exe&quot; 
                -verb:sync 
                -source:contentpath=&quot;$(OutDir)\MyApp.Precompiled&quot; 
                -dest:contentpath=&quot;D:\dev.myapp&quot;,computername=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,username=userid,password=password" 
                ContinueOnError="false" />
```

I actually also tried with computername as `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd`.

*EDIT:  The following is what I got.
EXEC: FileOrFolderNotFound
 EXEC: Object of type 'contentPath' and path 'E:\Builds\1...\dev.myapp' cannot be created.
 EXEC: The path '\?\E:\Builds\1...\dev.myapp' is not valid.
 EXEC: 1.
 E:\Builds\1...\BuildType\Targets\Deploy.targets (142): The command ""C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\MSDeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentpath="E:\Builds\1...\dev.myapp" -dest:contentpath="D:\dev.myapp",computername=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd,username=userid,password=password" exited with code -1.
I realize I haven't read all of the error, Do I really need an UNC path?*

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please post what errors you had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found out how to make it work.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\MSDeploy.exe&quot; 
            -verb:sync 
            -source:contentpath=&quot;$(OutDir)\MyApp.Precompiled&quot; 
            -dest:contentpath=&quot;D:\dev.myapp&quot;,computername=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd,username=userid,password=password,authtype=Basic 
            -allowUntrusted=True" 
            ContinueOnError="false" />
```

I changed computername to **computername=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd**, added **authtype=Basic** and **allowUntrusted=True** and voila it worked.

It was quite frustrating not having any kind of feedback of what went wrong with the first option. But when I was using the second alternative I got feedback to work with.

If anyone know how to make this work using the MSBuild task, please feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Try [dirPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207412) provider instead of contentPath, it'll behave more like a folder sync rather than IIS web site deployment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it though but in that case I need to use the built in Administrator account which is not allowed at my current client.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the sync worked using the EXEC task, did you make sure you have the **Microsoft.WebApplication.targets** in your csproj (or vbproj) file? I could see it just ignoring that msbuild task without the correct targets file included.

For example in my web service project files, I have this towards the bottom of my csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```